# BC30260 error <control id> is already declared as 'Friend WithEvents <control id> as control in this class

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am developing a WPF application using MS Visual Studio 2015.
The application has a number of XAML files with VB code behind, and has been working fine in debug mode.

However, when building the application, every control I have seems to give the same error.  For example, for a simple button I added to test this issue called "btnTestButton"  like:

```
<Button x:Name="btnTestButton"/>
```

Even when adding this, I get the same error:

**btnTestButton' is already declared as 'Friend WithEvents btnTestButton As Button' in this class**

As I said, this happens with every single control, whatever I rename them to.
I have googled for this, and the advice normally seems to be that there must be two controls named the same, but I'm certain that this is not the case.

Comment: Make sure that you haven't accidentally named two windows' classes the same. The file names are probably different but they might have the same class name. Look for any duplicates of `Public Class (name here)` in the `.xaml.vb` files and `<Window x:Name="(name here)">` in the `.xaml` files.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The application has over 50 xaml files, so I'm thinking of backing them up  deleting them all and trying to build with just one of them to see if I still get the error.  If the error still happens with just 1 xaml file, then something gone drastically wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Gah!

Basically, I somehow managed to include the entire debug folder before publishing which resulted in duplicates identified in the "design" files.

After much faffing and losing a days work I managed to get the app published.